# Why Auth::user()->is_admin; returns false in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

This doesn't work (nothing is displayed):

```
echo Auth::user()->is_admin;
```

This, however, works fine (the column value is displayed):

```
echo DB::table('users')->where('id', Auth::id())->value('is_admin');
```

When having just `echo Auth::user()` then this is displayed:
{"id":19,"name":"peeter","email":"peeter@test.com","is_admin":false}

As you can see it returns all the other column values just fine but "is_admin" column value is for some reason "false", no matter what the column value or type is set in phpmyadmin.

For example this is my full code that I put in web.php to test this:

```
Route::get('/testing', function(){
    echo Auth::user()->is_admin;
    echo DB::table('users')->where('id', auth::id())->value('is_admin');
});
```

I expected `echo Auth::user()->is_admin;` or `echo Auth::user()` to return the value of the "is_admin" column instead of displaying nothing or FALSE.

EDIT:

Thanks for the comments below, `var_dump()` helped to verify that it always sees it as boolean and the value is always false, even though in phpmyadmin it shows different value and no matter what data type I change it to, `var_dump()` always shows `bool(false)`.
I just added another column in phpmyadmin and it sees the correct value now, however it sees it as integer, not a boolean. So I guess it must be a mysql bug.

DIGGING DEEPER INTO THE RABBIT HOLE:
When I renamed the old column and change the new column name to "is_admin" then new one doesn't work anymore and old one works. So it seems like the issue is the column name! Works fine when I rename the column to anything else other than "is_admin". Very strange!

EDIT:
After renaming the column in phpmyadmin then `var_dump()` shows that it is integer int(1), not a boolean anymore, even when I change the datatype to BOOLEAN. When I change the column name back to the old is_admin then `var_dump()` shows that it is boolean again.

In User.php model, when I delete this code then everything works:

```
public function getIsAdminAttribute()
{
    return $this->roles()->where('id', 1)->exists();
}

public function roles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class);
}
```

However now it doesn't see the column value as Boolean. It always sees it as Integer, but at least the value is updated when I change it in the database.

EDIT:
Just to be clear, unless I have deleted the code from User.php, for the user who's ID is 1, "is_admin" column value is always bool(true), even if I change the value. For other users it's always bool(false).

Comment: can you add your class User to your question?

Comment: Can you post the exact response of the echo in your second piece of code (the route /testing)

Comment: If it is returning FALSE, and you displaying using echo then it will not display anything.
Instead, you can use ```var_dump()``` or ```dd()``` to see datatype of the value

Comment: Auth::user() doesn't return User model, that's why you can't reach user data directly.

Comment: THANK YOU. var_dump() helped to verify that it always sees it as boolean and the value is always false, even though in phpmyadmin it shows different value and no matter what data type I change it to, it always shows bool(false). 
I tried adding another column and everything works correctly with the new one. So I guess it's a phpmyadmin/mysql bug?

Comment: Seems like it works fine when renaming the column anything other than "is_admin". That's weird.

Comment: @peeter it is neither a phpMyAdmin bug or a Laravel bug, most likely you have a mutator in place for that attribute.

Comment: afaik, `getIsAdminAttribute` is an accessor for `is_admin`. so it dictate the output for that particular property. anyway, may we know the laravel version you used? if i remember correctly this pattern was used before laravel 8.

Comment: I am using Laravel 9 currently.
Just to be clear, unless I have deleted the piece of code from User.php, for the user who's ID is 1 "is_admin" column value always returns bool(true), even if I change the value. For other users it's always bool(false).

Answer (score 1):

The `echo false` statement will not display anything, since `false` will be converted to an empty string. Try to change it to something like this:

```
echo Auth::user()->is_admin ? 'admin' : 'no admin';
```

You could also typecast it like this:

```
echo (int) Auth::user()->is_admin;
```

You can read more in the PHP manual [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.casting).

Comment: still doesnt answer OP's question as "why is it converted to boolean when it is not so in the DB?".

Comment: I seem to misunderstand the question in that case. As far as I can see, the value is defined as boolean and the echo statements will fail at displaying anything when the value is false and be a misleading way to debug.

Answer (score -1):

After reading your question, it appears that this code will assist in your problem-solving.

Add a scope to your User model; see the [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent#local-scopes) for additional information.

```php
<?php
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable;

    // Your model stuff ...

    public function scopeIsAdmin() {
        return (bool) $this->is_admin;
    }
}
```

Then, you can access this as seen below.

```php
$is_admin = auth()->user()->isAdmin();
dd($is_admin);
// it will display true
```

Happy Coding!...

Comment: scope need to return query builder instance not boolean result

Comment: is this chatgpt-powered answer? thing is, `scope` is not an `accessor`, it used to help filtering stuff.

Comment: @Bagus Tesa, No brother. :)

I used this pattern in my project since I start work with Laravel. not every answer is powered by ChatGPT, sometimes we are giving answers based on our own experiences ;)

Comment: you need to use an accessor(mutator) not a scope or use a direct method if you want. scopes are meant to return an eloquent Builder::class instance. If you use a scope like that, it's not a scope literally, it's just a state method or an attribute. You should read the documentation you linked.

Comment: @N69S, you can check in Laravel documentation for the same.
You can do anything using the scope function, it is just a public static function which you can reuse in your project.

Comment: first, it is not a static function even if you can use it statically. Second, in the documentation you linked it litterally  says `Scopes should always return the same query builder instance or void:` (not boolean if that is not clear)

Comment: Yes, agree. as it is return ```void``` too, means you can add your business logic in the Scope function, right ?

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. What did you change, and why?

Comment: @NicoHaase, Just change "IsActive" to "IsAdmin"

Comment: I will tell you why the use of scope in your example is bad. You start with a model instance, when you call a scope, it will first land on the method `function __call($method, $parameters)` which will initiate a new query builder with `$this->newQuery()`, then it will always return false since its a new model instance.

Comment: @MiteshRathod please add all clarification to your question by editing it. I would assume that changing the name of the field (or getter) is not the crucial point here, but the usage of `dd`  compared to `echo`?

Comment: Wow, this answer helped. Now I get the boolean datatype, no matter the column name. Thanks. Still a mystery why I was getting anomalies with my code.